# Vuetify set outlined for all v-text-field by default

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settings, vuetify.js, default

Is there are simple way to change default value of props "outlined" for all "v-text-field" across entered project?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create a wrapper component and [`extends`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) from `VTextField` (see [treeshaking](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#a-la-carte-treeshaking)) and customise the default value(s).

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.component('TextFieldOutlined', {
  extends: VTextField,
  props: {
    outlined: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  }
})
```

Using it like:

```html
<text-field-outlined
  label="Some label"
  clearable
  dense>
</text-field-outlined>
```

FWIW, extending a component means all base component's props are passed along and thus equally usable.

Comment: Perfect. Was looking for something similar regarding the VBtn component. This is a great and simple solution.

Comment: It should definitely be marked as the solution. That's clean, still allows to override the props at particular places if needed, and can be applied to any prop besides "outlined".

Comment: What about Composition API? The "extends" is designed for Options API and does not handle the merging of the setup() hook.

Answer (score 0):

The `extends` is not good way for Vue 3 (Composition API).
You need create own control based on v-text-field.

But for Vuetify 3 you need use [Global configuration](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/global-configuration/)

I didn't try this code. But I think something like this:

```
createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    VTextField: { variant: 'outlined' },
  },
})
```

Comment: Can you please give more details directly in the answer?

Comment: Ok. I have appended some code