# How to change Vuetify v-text-field outlined border

Tags: css, styles, border, vuetify.js, textfield

I have been strying to override the default border color of **outlined** v-text-field. Basically I want a specific color all the times (unfocused, focused, hover) playing with the codepen below:

https://codepen.io/hoiratnhieu/pen/GRpjEeb

```
<v-text-field
              label="Outlined"
              outlined
              dense
            ></v-text-field>
```

Can someone provide some much needed help here?

Thank you.

Comment: I would also be very interested in the answer to this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuetify set outlined for all v-text-field by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894355/vuetify-set-outlined-for-all-v-text-field-by-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the following CSS:

```
.v-text-field--outlined fieldset {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SASS variables, customize the light theme like this:

```
// Your custom main.scss

$material-light: (
  'text-fields': (
    'outlined': rgba(0,0,0, 0.19),
    'outlined-hover': rgba(0,0,0, 0.38),
  ),
);
```

The focus color is simply the primary color. You can overwrite all variables in `@vuetify/src/styles/settings/_light.scss` like that.