# How to change outline color v-text-field vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Does someone knows how to change the outlined color of the v-text-field component.
[Click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKqoK.jpg)

Comment: This should be the border. `border-color: red;`.

Comment: The problem is that the doesn't work on the v-text-field for some reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuetify set outlined for all v-text-field by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894355/vuetify-set-outlined-for-all-v-text-field-by-default)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can override the default style using deep selector. The original css is on the `fieldset` element, so you need to target that aswell.

```
<style scoped>
.v-text-field--outlined >>> fieldset {
  border-color: rgba(192, 0, 250, 0.986);
}
</style>
```

Comment: alternatively you could use ::v-deep as a deep selector instead of >>>

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Vuetify 3 for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `color attribute` like following:

```
<v-text-field
   label="Your landing page"
    hint="www.example.com/page"
    persistent-hint
    outlined
    color="red"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: This only changes the color on focus though

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SASS variables, customize the light theme like this:

```
// Your custom main.scss

$material-light: (
  'text-fields': (
    'outlined': rgba(0,0,0, 0.19),
  ),
);
```

You can overwrite all variables in `@vuetify/src/styles/settings/_light.scss` like that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Mohammad Hosseini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9353539/mohammad-hosseini), this is the only RIGHT ANSWER

```
.v-text-field--outlined:not(.v-input--is-focused):not(.v-input--has-state)
> .v-input__control
> .v-input__slot
fieldset {
color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.33);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.v-application .transparent {  
     border-color: black !important;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file related to CSS styles in the Styles section and name it Override. In that file, you can make any desired changes you need. Put the following code in that file, you can change the color of the border:

```
.theme--light.v-text-field--outlined:not(.v-input--is-focused):not(.v-input--has-state)
    > .v-input__control
    > .v-input__slot
    fieldset {
    color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.33);
  }
```